# I installed Sebwite category sidebar but it's not showing up in my sidebar

Tags: magento2.4.4, sidebar

Hi I installed Sebwite category sidebar but it's not showing up in my sidebar.
It shows up the admin page and I configured it on the admin page but I can't see it on the category sidebar. I am using a luma custom theme.

https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install it to the latest version of Magento it will not work as it was last updated 5 years ago there are fewer chances that it will be compatible with latest version.

Comment: I did install it on version 2.4.4 but I actually installed the updated one which is this one
https://github.com/groomershop/magento2-category-sidebar

Is it not compatible too?